# Using a foreign key in a loop with symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have three tables. Two use a foreign key that pulls in data and one that displays the data.

My tables are like this:

```
department:
id: 1  name: illustration
id: 2  name  photography
etc...

type:
id: 1  name: ink
id: 2  name: charcoal
etc...

user:
id: 1 firstname: Fred    lastname: Flintstone
id: 2 firstname: Barney  lastname: Rubble
etc....
```

So I want to display the data in an order according to department with the type and user data in the row.

For instance:

```
Illustration
ink       Fred Flintstone
charcoal  Fred Flintstone
painting  Fred Flintstone

Photography
ink      Barney Rubble
painting Barney Rubble
```

What I have so far works, but I think it can be executed much better. This is whatI have that works:

apps/frontend/modules/foo/actions/actions.class.php

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->illustration = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->where('a.department_id = 1')
      ->execute();

    $this->photography = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->where('a.department_id = 2')
      ->execute();
 }
```

And in the index
apps/frontend/modules/foo/templates/indexSuccess.php

```
<?php foreach ($illustration as $user): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="displayDept" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getDepartment() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($illustration as $user): ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getType() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getUrl() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo simple_format_text($user->getDescription()) ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getDateTimeObject('created_at')->format('m/d/Y') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
     <tr>
    <?php foreach ($photography as $me): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="displayDept" valign="top"><?php echo $me->getDepartment() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($photography as $me): ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $me->getType() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $me->getUrl() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo simple_format_text($me->getDescription()) ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $me->getDateTimeObject('created_at')->format('m/d/Y') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, this works, but what if the department list gets really long. That means I have to make a new database query in the actions and use the foreach option in the indexSuccess.php file.

Is there a way to pull all of the department data with a WHERE option on the subsequent data in the row?

**UPDATE**

Here is the schema, which I think is pretty close to what @ManseUK suggested:

```
Department:
 actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

Type:
 actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  user_id: { type: integer(4) }

User:
 actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  firstname: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  lastname: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  email: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  department_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  type_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  url: { type: string(255), notnull:true }
  description: { type: string(4000) }
 relations:
  Department: { class: Department, local: department_id, foreign: id }
  Type: { class: Type, local: type_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your schema.yml its difficult to say - but if you have setup the aliases within the schema correctly then you should be able to do something like :

actions.php

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->departments = Doctrine_Core::getTable('departments')
      ->findAll(); 
    // returns all departments or you could change this to just select departments by name / id
}
```

indexSuccess.php

```
<?php foreach ($departments as $dept): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="displayDept" valign="top"><?php echo $dept->getName() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($dept->getUsers() as $user): ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getType() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getUrl() ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo simple_format_text($user->getDescription()) ?></td>
      <td class="displayInfo" valign="top"><?php echo $user->getDateTimeObject('created_at')->format('m/d/Y') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

schema.yml

```
Department:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name: String(25)
Type:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name: String(25)
User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    firstname: string(25)
    lastname: string(25)
    department: integer
    type: integer
    relations:
      Department:
        class: Department
        local: department
        foreign: id
        foreignAlias: Users
      Type:
        class: Type
        local: type
        foreign: id
        foreignAlias: Users
```

The `foreignAlias` param is the key here - it specifics the relationship name between tables - allowing you to call `$dept->getUsers()` - which returns all users for a specific department

Comment: I used your suggested and it threw this error:

**Unknown record property / related component "users" on "Department"**

Comment: @CareyEstes did you rebuild your classes (doctrine:build --all-classes) ?

Comment: Yes, and cleared the cache. I noticed I did not have a foreignAlias: Users in my Schema for department relations (see above schema). Would this be throwing the Error? I have since added the foreignAlias:Users but still no luck. Getting the same Unknown record property error

Comment: Its the foreignAlias that will make this work - have a look in your base class thats created for `Department` and see if there is a property definition like this -> `@property Doctrine_Collection $Users`

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you very much! If its not too much trouble could you explain how that works? Because the User table is a foreignAlias to the Department table, I can pull data from there without creating a query? 

It does not make sense, it seems like magic. That has been my experience with Symfony so far though. 

Also, I did have @property Doctrine_Collection $Users in BaseDepartment.class.php after I did a rebuild. It was commented out though. Not sure how that works either.

Thanks again!